# Allow managed code in hosted environment to call back unmanaged code

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli, clr-hosting

I have C++ code that hosts a clr in order to make use of Managed.dll, written in c#.

This .net has a method like the following that allows code to register for notification of events:

```
public void Register(IMyListener listener);
```

The interface looks something like this

```
public interface IMyListener
{
    void Notify(string details);
}
```

I'd like to do stuff in the C++ part of the program, triggered by the events in the .net world. I would not even mind creating another managed dll for the sole purpose of making Managed.dll more C++-friendly, if that is necessary.

What are my options here? The only one I am sure I could implement is this:

- Write another managed dll that listens for those events, queues them and lets the C++ code access the queue via polling

This would of course change from an 'interrupt' style to a 'polling' style with all its advantages and disadvantages and the need to provide for queuing. Can we do without polling? Could I somehow call managed code and provide it a function pointer into the C++ world as the argument?

**Update**
Thanks to stijn's answer and comments I hope I moved a bit in the right direction, but I guess the main problem still open is how to pass a fn pointer from unmanaged land into the clr hosted environment.

Say I have an "int fn(int)" type of function pointer that I want to pass to the managed world, here are the relevant parts:

**Managed code** (C++/CLI)

```
typedef int (__stdcall *native_fun)( int );

String^ MyListener::Register(native_fun & callback)
{
    return "MyListener::Register(native_fun callback) called callback(9): " + callback(9);
}
```

**Unmanaged code**

```
typedef int (__stdcall *native_fun)( int );
extern "C" static int __stdcall NativeFun(int i)
{
    wprintf(L"Callback arrived in native fun land: %d\n", i);
    return i * 3;
}
void callCLR()
{
    // Setup CLR hosting environment
    ...
    // prepare call into CLR
    variant_t vtEmpty;
    variant_t vtRetValue;
    variant_t vtFnPtrArg((native_fun) &NativeFun);
    SAFEARRAY *psaMethodArgs = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 1);
    LONG index = 0;
    SafeArrayPutElement(psaMethodArgs, &index, &vtFnPtrArg);
    ...
    hr = spType->InvokeMember_3(bstrMethodName, static_cast<BindingFlags>(
            BindingFlags_InvokeMethod | BindingFlags_Static | BindingFlags_Public),
            NULL, vtEmpty, psaMethodArgs, &vtRetValue);
    if (FAILED(hr))
            wprintf(L"Failed to invoke function: 0x%08lx\n", hr);
```

The `spType->InvokeMember_3` call will lead to a `0x80131512` result.

Something seems to be wrong with the way I pass the pointer to NativeFun over to the managed world, or how my functions are defined. When using a String^ param instead of the fn ptr, I can call the CLR function successfully.

Comment: your CLI method takes a `native_fun&` but you're passing a `native_fun`, could that be the problem? Have you tried passing pointers instead (eg `native_fun*`)? Can you attach a debugger (eventually by putting a `DebugBreak` somewhere) and see if the value for the argument is passed correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You can write a seperate dll in C++/CLI and implement the interface there, and forward the logic to C++. From my experience with mixing managed/unmanaged I can say using an intermediate C++/CLI step is the way to go. No fiddling with DllImport and functions only, but a solid bridge between both worlds. It just takes some getting used to the syntax and marshalling, but once you have that it's practically effortless. If you need to hold C++ objects in the managed class, best way is to use something [like clr_scoped_ptr](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/scoped-ptr-for-c-cli-ensure-managed-object-properly-frees-owned-native-object).

Code would look like this:

```
//header
#using <Managed.dll>

//forward declare some native class
class NativeCppClass;

public ref class MyListener : public IMylIstener
{
public:
  MyListener();

    //note cli classes automatically implement IDisposable,
    //which will call this destructor when disposed,
    //so used it as a normal C++ destructor and do cleanup here
  ~MyListener();

  virtual void Notify( String^ details );

private:
  clr_scoped_ptr< NativeCppClass > impl;
}

//source
#include "Header.h"
#include <NativeCppClass.h>

//here's how I marshall strings both ways
namespace
{
  inline String^ marshal( const std::string& i )
  {
    return gcnew String( i.data() );
  }

  inline std::string marshal( String^ i )
  {
    if( i == nullptr )
      return std::string();
    char* str2 = (char*) (void*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi( i );
    std::string sRet( str2 );
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal( IntPtr( str2 ) );
    return sRet;
  }
}

MyListener::MyListener() :
  impl( new NativeCppClass() )
{
}

MyListener::~MyListener()
{
}

void MyListener::Notify( String^ details )
{
  //handle event here
  impl->SomeCppFunctionTakingStdString( marshal( details ) );
}
```

**update**
Here's a simple solution to call callbacks in C++ from the managed world:

```
pubic ref class CallbackWrapper
{
public:
  typedef int (*native_fun)( int );

  CallbackWrapper( native_fun fun ) : fun( fun ) {}

  void Call() { fun(); }

  CallbackWrapper^ Create( ... ) { return gcnew CallbackWrapper( ... ); }

private:
  native_fun fun;
}
```

you can also wrap this in an Action if you want.
Another way is using `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`, for example [as in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282264/pass-a-function-pointer-from-c-to-be-called-by-c-sharp-arguments-of-function)

Comment: So if I wanted to pass a fn pointer (or instance of a class) from unmanaged code over to the managed C++/CLI code, I'd change the MyListener constructor to accept a value for the impl parameter, I guess. Looks like it could work, will check it out.

Comment: yes that's a possibility. Fo such cases I usually supply a factory method taking managed parameters telling what and how to create something, then create an instance passing unmanaged args to the constructor of MyListener. You can also make a managed delegate call an unmanaged function or vice-versa, search for `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` examples

Comment: Almost there, I hope. Still need to figure out how to build the correct type of C++/CLI dll. I tried `/clr` and `/clr:pure` (/clr:safe and /clr:oldSyntax would abort compilation with errors), but both will lead to error `0x8007000b` when doing `AppDomain->Load_2()`. Otoh I wonder if, for just passing an unmanaged fn pointer to managed C# land, there isn't a way to just 'typedef' the fn signature somewhere in C# and pass the pointer over to the managed dll (which I have no problems loading via AppDomain->Load_2 and calling methods in) - will see what `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` has in store

Comment: Are you sure I can access the C++/CLI dll using CLR hosting? I kinda get the feeling that won't work (it works with a standard C# dll though). But I think I have to use CLR hosting, because I don't control the .exe file, (it's node.exe), I can only extend it via C++ libraries (like the one I'm currently using to host a CLR so that I can access the functionality of a managed dll).

Comment: I normally use /clr for my dlls (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85344whh.aspx). 0x8007000b -> you're not mixing 32/64bit or so? For passing funptrs around you definitely need some translation. I don't think there's a problem with tghe hosted environment.. If it can load .net dlls it can load mixed ones as well. When looked at from outside, there's no difference between a dll written completely in C# for instance, or one written in C++/CLI

Comment: You were right about the 32/64 mix. That solved the dll loading problem. (After figuring out that I had to manually add the x64 platform target for the C++/CLI project, whereas for other project types I could just choose it from a list) Thanks! Now I'm stuck one step further - invoking the fn and passing the fn ptr. But that's for tomorrow...

Comment: OK, I can now invoke methods with String parameters in the C++/CLI dll (which is what I was able to do with the C# dll), but I don't know how to pass a fn ptr from the unmanaged world, even of the simple signature `typedef int (__stdcall *CB)(int);`. Google didn't have any examples for me, either. All I could find is how to call unmanaged code via DllImport, actually having to reference a named dll in the managed code. I want the managed code to know nothing more than the fn ptr that I give it at runtime. Obviously the signature of the fn the ptr points to must be known.

Comment: Giving up. Have to deliver a product... So I'll go with plan B for now, which involves a completely different solution in .net, which means I can directly access managed dlls. Thanks stijn for your great help, it really brought me a lot closer to where I wanted to go, but somehow can't seem to pass unmanaged fn pointers to managed code.

Comment: Although I gave up on CLR Hosting, thanks to stijn pointing me in the direction of C++/CLI I finally figured with C++/CLI I can do completely without CLR hosting. So thanks for that. Still haven't figured out the answer to my question, but do not need it any more for the project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still needs a better way for this , you can simply pass **c++ function to CLR using `intptr_t` in variant and `long` in managed** , then use Marshall and delegate to invoke your native function , super easy and works like charm.

if you need a code snippet , let me know.

Comment: Could you provide the code snippet, please? I could really need it!