# Calling C++ DLL with a callback function that contains a char* from C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a C++ DLL (*SimpleDLL.dll*), with a exposed function (*DllFunctionPoibnterGetName*) that has a function pointer (*getNameFP*). The function pointer takes a char * as a parameter (*char * name*).

```
// C++ 
DllExport void DllFunctionPoibnterGetName( void (*getNameFP) (char * name, unsigned short * length ) ) {

    char name[1024];
    unsigned short length = 0 ; 
    getNameFP( name, &length ); 

    printf( "length=[%d] name=[%s]\n", length, name ); 
}
```

I have a C# application that would like to use this C++ DLL.

```
// C# 
public unsafe delegate void GetName( System.Char* name, System.UInt16* length); 
unsafe class Program
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void delegateGetName(System.Char* name, System.UInt16* length);

    [DllImport("SimpleDLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi )]
    public static extern void DllFunctionPoibnterGetName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] delegateGetName getName);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        DllFunctionPoibnterGetName(GetName); 
    }

    static void GetName(System.Char* name, System.UInt16* length)
    {
        // name = "one two three";
        *length = 10; 
    }   
}
```

Currently I can set the length with out any problems, but I can't seem to find a way to set the name correctly.

**My Question is**

- How do I set the *char ** name to a value correctly.

Comment: consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282264/pass-a-function-pointer-from-c-to-be-called-by-c-sharp-arguments-of-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use unsafe code. You can do it like this:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void delegateGetName(IntPtr name, out ushort length);
....
static void GetName(IntPtr name, out ushort length)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("one two three");
    length = (ushort)buffer.Length;
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, name, buffer.Length);
}
```

Although this interface design is just asking for a buffer overrun. How are you supposed to know how big the unmanaged buffer is? It would make more sense for the `length` parameter to be passed by `ref`. On input it would tell you how big the buffer is. On output you would have recorded how many bytes you copied into the buffer.

Comment: Hello Thank you, Yes, I realize that if I don't declare how big the buffer is that I might have a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the char* as a char[]. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Casting the char will not do. The char * data is 'unmanaged', native data. And C# uses 'managed', .NET data.

You need to make a wrapper for your call and use marschall to convert the data from 'unmanaged' to 'managed'.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308584/how-to-return-text-from-native-c-code