# How to pass function pointer from C# to a C++ Dll?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, delegates, pinvoke

The function defined in C++ dll is:

```
static double (*Func1)(double);
EXTERN_C __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall double TestDelegate(double (*fun)(double))
{
    Func1 = fun;
    return Func1(25.0);
}


void My_Real_purpose()
{
    SomeClass a;
    a.SetFunction(Func1);//Define behaviour of a by C# in runtime
    a.DoSomething();//Even I want it runs in another thread!
}
```

And I tried to call it in C# like this:

```
    class A
    {
        [DllImport("DllName.dll")]
        public extern static double TestDelegate(IntPtr f);

        public delegate double MyFuncDelegate(double x);

        public static double MyFunc(double x)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(x);
        }

        static MyFuncDelegate ff;
        static GCHandle gch;
        public static double Invoke()
        {
            ff = new MyFuncDelegate(MyFunc);
            gch = GCHandle.Alloc(ff);  
            double c = TestDelegate(Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(ff));//Error occurs this line
            gch.Free();
            return c;
        }

    }
```

It is compiled without error.But when it runs,VS2012 display an error of "Access Violation Exception".

I have searched and tried a lot of ways,such as passing a delegate rather than a IntPtr,but all of them turned out to be failed.

So,what is the correct way to use an API function in a dll which contains function pointer?Or how to realize "My_Real_purpose" function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a function pointer from C++ to be called by C# - Arguments of functions include a wide char string (LPCWSTR)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282264/pass-a-function-pointer-from-c-to-be-called-by-c-sharp-arguments-of-function)

Comment: I removed the COM tag, as this question has nothing to do with COM; the PInvoke tag is more appropriate.

Comment: The delegate declaration is wrong, but that is not enough to explain the AVE.  Be sure you know how to debug the C++ code so you can diagnose this crash.  Show the stack trace you get.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your delegate uses the `cdecl` calling convention. In C# you would therefore declare the delegate like this:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate double CallbackDelegate(double x);
```

As an alternative, you could decide to declare the function pointer in C++ as `__stdcall`, in which case you would remove the `UnmanagedFunctionPointer` attribute and rely on the default calling convention being `CallingConvention.StdCall`.

Implement it like this:

```
public static double MyFunc(double x)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(x);
}
```

In order to keep the unmanaged function pointer alive (guarding against GC), you need to hold an instance of the delegate in a variable.

```
private static CallbackDelegate delegateInstance;
....
delegateInstance = MyFunc;
```

In the simple example that you have here, the C++ code does not use the unmanaged function pointer outside of `TestDelegate`, but in a more complex example you may do so, in which case you must keep the unmanaged function pointer alive.

The function that you import is declared like this:

```
[DllImport("DllName.dll")]
public extern static double TestDelegate(CallbackDelegate f);
```

You can then call it like this:

```
double retval = TestDelegate(delegateInstance);
```

Answer (score 3):

On the C++ side, I'd explicitly specify the *calling convention* for the callback, e.g. `__stdcall` (you haven't done that in your code, and I think the default is `__cdecl`):

```
// Include the calling convention (__stdcall) for the Callback
typedef double (__stdcall * Callback)(double);

// Just use "Callback" here, instead of repeating 
// the above function prototype
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall double TestDelegate(Callback func)
{
    return func(25.0);
}

// BTW: Can export also using .DEF file to avoid __stdcall name mangling
```

On the C# side, you can try something like this:

```
public delegate double CallbackDelegate(double x);

// PInvoke declaration for the native DLL exported function
[DllImport("YourDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern double TestDelegate(CallbackDelegate func);

private double MyFunctionCallback(double x)
{
    // ... Implement your C# callback code ...
}

CallbackDelegate managedDelegate = new CallbackDelegate(MyFunctionCallback);

// Call into the native DLL, passing the managed callback
TestDelegate(managedDelegate);
```