# Pass function pointer into a DLL from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dll, delegates, interopservices

#### Problem

I have a DLL with the following function exported.

```
extern void Finalize(void (*WriteEntry)(const char* entry));
```

I am using P-Invoke to call into the DLL from PowerShell.

In PowerShell scripts, I have a function `WriteEntry` defined, which I need to be invoked whenever `Finalize` invokes the `WriteEntry` function pointer.

---

#### My approach so far

It seems like the right approach is to create a C-style wrapper around the `WriteEntry` PowerShell function, where the wrapper is passed to `Finalize` as the function pointer.

After doing some investigation, I found out about creating a delegate which can interoperate with unmanaged code (See [How to pass function pointer from C# to a C++ Dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226928/how-to-pass-function-pointer-from-c-sharp-to-a-c-dll)). I created the following `CallbackDelegate` type.  I was able to pass it from C# code to the DLL. Now, I need a way for a PowerShell application to be able to construct the delegate and pass it to the DLL.

```
$delegateTypeDefinition = @'
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedFunctionPointer(System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public delegate void CallbackDelegate([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string entry);
'@
```

---

#### Where I'm stuck

I'm not sure how to wrap the CallbackDelegate delegate around the `WriteEntry` PowerShell function.

So, the question that I believe that I need answered is, how do we construct a delegate from a PowerShell function.  If that turns out to be an XY problem, I hope that I have provided enough details to be pointed in the correct direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe you can do what you're asking with PowerShell alone, at least not without jumping through a series of hoops to create a class inheriting from `MulticastDelegate` and then attempting to register it. PowerShell doesn't have an equivalent of the `delegate` keyword for defining one easily.

We can instead define the C# source for doing so, and ultimately perform the invocation from PowerShell itself. We already need to `P/Invoke` from PowerShell, so we'll just keep your `delegate` definition provided in C# form.

---

A `delegate` is functionally equivalent (no pun intended) in C# to a callback in C++. A `Method` can be used as a `delegate`. An `Action` can be used as a `delegate`. A `Func` can be used as a `delegate`. At its core, a `delegate` is an executable block of code, in some form. So how does this translate to PowerShell?

PowerShell code will use a `ScriptBlock` `{}` in order to define executable blocks of code. These are used quite often, from function definitions, to method definitions on a class, to looping constructs, and more. A `ScriptBlock` can even be used and executed on its own using the call operator `&`. A `ScriptBlock` is just a schmancy name for an **unnamed function**. Since a `ScriptBlock` is a function, we can use that as the delegate value.

The kicker here is that `ScriptBlock` needs to be converted to your `delegate` type. And while we're at it, let's fix that mouthful of qualified type-names with a using statement

> **Note:** If your C# code is defined in a source file, you can instead read it in with
> `Get-Content -Raw`. If it is already compiled into a DLL, you can skip that part and use `Add-Type` providing the path to the DLL.

```
$delegateTypeDefinition = @"
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

# Here is the callback delegate you provided
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void CallbackDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string entry);

public static class DelegateHelper
{
  # Use your actual DLL
  [DllImport("DllName.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static extern void Finalize(CallbackDelegate del);
}
"@

# Compile your C# code
Add-Type $delegateTypeDefinition

# Define your delegate function with the correct parameters
[CallbackDelegate]$callbackDelegate = {
  Param(
    [string]$entry
  )

  # Your callback code here
}
```

*Normally* you would then call `$callbackDelegate.Invoke("some string")` to run your
C#-defined delegate function. But since you want to pass it to `Finalize`, we'll do that instead.

> **Note:** This is why we put the `DllImport` inside of a class. It does not have to be defined as a static class or member but imported `P/Invoke` functions have to be defined in *a* class like a method.

```
# Call Finalize
[DelegateHelper]::Finalize($callbackDelegate)
```

*In theory*, this should work for passing in the callback.

---

That said, `delegate` types, in particular when accessing members which have a `delegate` type, can behave somewhat funky in PowerShell. In addition, I don't have or know offhand of a native DLL to test this with myself. I can only guarantee `$callbackDelegate.Invoke("some value")` will work as far as setting assigning a `ScriptBlock` to a `delegate` type and invoking it.

If you run into more issues, or there's a "gotcha" with what I provided above in your use case, you said you got this working in C#. You may want to consider implementing this piece *entirely* in C# while additionally creating a public helper function on your helper class to take the `entry` string and run `Finalize` within the C# code. Use `Add-Type` to either compile the source from your script or load a pre-compiled DLL. From there you can run your helper function within PowerShell to execute the `Finalize` function. It's a bit of a cop-out, but `delegate` types are an area where PowerShell can be difficult to work with at times.